# Difference in focus between lenses and glasses

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

I have both glasses and contact lenses.

The prescriptions are both recent and up to date.

I am 46, so I'm starting to have a harder time to focus on things that are very close to my eyes, compared to 10 years ago.

With lenses, I notice it takes some efforts to read text very close to my eyes,  but with my glasses, I don't have the same problem at all.

Does the distance between the eye and the lens explain this? and, if yes, how? or could it be other factors (lower material quality, lenses rounded by .25, etc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really a question that should be addressed to an optician familiar with the person involved.

Comment: Same eyeballs, two different sets of lenses, two results; what does it have to do with the person? it's the only part that is not a variable.

Comment: @StephenG This is a basic question about optics, not a personal request for medical advice.

Comment: Anyone with the knowledge to answer this question will realise you're a little short-sighted, but it wouldn't hurt to mention the strength of your glasses/  lenses (a rough approximation is sufficient, there's no need to reveal personal details). My guess is around -2 to -4 dioptres.

Comment: The lenses are -5 and -3.25, not sure about the glasses, but the doctor told that the prescription is different due to the distance to the eye. Since both are supposedly 'matched', I don't get why they both behave differently.

Comment: @PM2Ring An optician would explain that any problem with vision can be related to a biological issue, not, as you put it a "basic question about optics".  Without wishing to alarm the OP, please note that if you don't tell your optician you have a problem,  they cannot check for any of the medical reasons you might have one.  It's best to explain these things to people who *know* these things.

Comment: @StephenG, if the eye ball is the same and the result is only different with a different lens, wouldn't that dictate that most likely the lens is the reason for the difference?

Comment: There is a similar question on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/answers/comments/2qumf3/eli5_why_can_i_see_better_wearing_eye_glasses/ but it's about someone with astigmatism, however lens material, distortion around edge of lenses, etc came up in the discussion

Comment: @Thomas An eyeball in contact with something is fundamentally different from an eyeball with a correcting lens at some distance from it.

Comment: They write about this on londonvisionclinic.com, where they say that the distance eye-lens has an impact on visual acuity; how is what I'm trying to understand. I read that the eyeball shape changes slightly when you have a lens, but apparently this remains for hours after the lens is removed so it doesn't explain the difference in this case.

Comment: @StephanG The prescriptions are new, so Thomas has recently seen an optometrist / optician, who would have informed him about any serious eye condition. Most people begin to get presbyopia somewhere around their 40s: the lens becomes stiffer, making it harder to change focus, and to focus on close objects.

Comment: That can be a little upsetting, especially if you're myopic, and so have always had better close vision than normal, but it's actually not so bad, since it counteracts the myopia to an extent. After more than 4 decades of wearing glasses or contacts, I rarely bother wearing glasses now that I'm in my late 50s.

Comment: If the prescription is different, that would explain the difference in performance.

Comment: @sammy, the different prescriptions are supposed to yield similar results when worn at different distances (lenses vs. glasses).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't know that.

Comment: If your glasses have bifocal lenses, then the lower part of the glasses will correct for the presbyopia and the upper for the myopia.  The contact lenses are probably not bifocal, so only correct for myopia.  Unfortunately, practical applications like this aren't "on topic" at this site, but I don't know which site would be proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your eye plus the corrective lens (whether on the surface, or some distance away) makes an "effective" lens with a focal length that depends on the distance between the eye and the lens.

When you are using contact lenses, that distance is fixed; when you have glasses, that distance is variable (by sliding the glasses towards the tip of the nose, or closer to your eyes).

Now typically the effect of glasses gets stronger as the lenses slide towards the tip of your nose: if you have positive diopter lenses (because you are far-sighted), you can see things closer up by sliding the lens further away; if you have negative diopter lenses (as you state), then pushing the lens closer will help.

Your optician selected lenses that had a certain curvature, expecting that they would give appropriate correction at a particular distance from the eye; but your glasses are working better than the contacts when you are looking close up, which tells me that you probably push your glasses a little closer to the eye than the optician was expecting.

You can experiment with this and let us know - does sliding the glasses towards the tip of your nose make it harder to read close-up?

The equation describing the effect (assuming two thin lenses with focal length $f_1$, $f_2$ and separated by a small distance $d$) is [the Back Focal Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Compound_lenses)

$$\rm{BFL}=\frac{f_2(d-f_1)}{d-(f_1+f_2)}$$

Comment: As a long time glasses wearer, I can assure you that this is backward: negative focal length lenses are functionally stronger when closer to the eye and weaker when further. That’s why glasses prescriptions are significantly stronger than contacts prescriptions.

Comment: @Ben51 it’s late and you are probably right that I misstated that. I will edit this when I am fully awake...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because of the effectively smaller aperture when using glasses. Blurriness depends not only on how close the image distance is to the location of the retina, but also on the size of the aperture. A pinhole doesn’t even have a focal length, but can form a reasonably clear image by restricting the aperture. If you don’t have your glasses, you can see distant objects clearly by looking through a small hole. The focal length of the lens in your eye is unchanged, but by eliminating all the rays far from the central axis (the ones that require a larger angle of refraction) you get rid of the blurring.

Now, moving a concave lens in front of your eye further away does effectively the same thing. Any rays far from the central axis are bent outward to the point that they no longer enter the pupil. As the distance grows, the total amount of light entering the eye decreases, but the incorrect focal length produces less blurring.